# Istio Gateway Reencrypt

Tags: ssl, istio

I have a service serving an https port, When I create a gateway and a virtual service, the only way I've managed to publish it is with PASSTHROUGHT TLS, is there a way to have a public Certificate in the gateway, and use PATH routes and then reencrypt the request for the internal TLS? With PASSTHROUGHT I am limited to SNS hosts

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: It's Openshift 4.7 baremetal, Istio 1.11

Comment: Did you try [Configure a TLS ingress gateway for multiple hosts](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/#configure-a-tls-ingress-gateway-for-multiple-hosts)?

Comment: Sorry, I got pulled to a pipeline issue, will go back to the Ingress after that